# Public_html file permissions

Tags: php, .htaccess, ftp

I'm building a site that uses many files,many of which should never be accessed via the browser. For example there's a mysql_conect script that every MYSQL query page users, but if the user were to navigate directly to that page via URL(example.php/mysqlconnect.php) the screen would return blank..How can I make it that the browser returns a 401 permission error when the user attempts to access  these files directly?

Comment: "`the screen would return blank`" - so what?

Comment: "Enhanced use experience" lol...The truth is that all you guys are right, it poses no security risk so I'll leave it for the time being. Thanks to all.

Comment: What is the use case for such a use experience? In what circumstances a fair user might encounter with this file?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do that. Unless you echo the values, you're safe.

PHP wont render in the browser unless told to do so. Many (all) scripts do what you're explaining.

Answer (score 1):

As @Paul says, there is no need to do that, the user will never see the content of the php file if he points the browser to example.php/mysqlconnect.php, but if you want you can drop a .htaccess file in the same directory where the mysql_connect.php script is with the following content:

```
<Files mysql_connect.php>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Or if you want to restrict access to the whole directory the content of the .htaccess file needs to be:

```
deny from all
```

Or

```
Options All -Indexes
```

You can see more configuration options in .htaccess files here:

[Htaccess tricks](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/)

Answer (score 0):

in particular situation you can place your file wherever you want and add the following code to your file

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'mysqlconnect.php')
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    exit;
```

so if the file is requested directly, it will return 401 status code and exit.